# Protect functions and var names on a javascript code

Tags: javascript

Im designing an API that requires my users to download a javascript file from my server and then load it on their pages. Inside this file there is a function call generic(), if my users include this js and for some reason they have a piece of js on their page where there is another function call generic() this will represent an issue. Im not a front end dev, I know that with php you can solve this creating a class and putting all your functions inside, so you can call them like $myclass->myfunction();, but how can i solve this on js? Is this even a good approach on js? (no jquery please.)

Comment: No jQuery, but you can take a jQuery-like approach and basically have one function that acts as a namespace, so then users would use `YourAPIName.generic();`, `YourAPIName.otherFunc()`, etc. Then you only have to worry about coming up with one reasonably descriptive and unlikely to clash name for your namespace, and you can use generic names for your methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will obviously always have to expose at least one identifier globally, but a common approach is to wrap everything in an immediately-invoked function expression:

```
var YourNamespace = (function () {

    var privateData = 10; // Not accessible outside the IIFE

    // Expose public properties (these functions can access the private data)
    return {
        someMethod: function () {
            // Do stuff
        },
        anotherMethod: function () {
            // More stuff
        }
    };

}());
```

This will expose a single identifier, `YourNamespace`, as an object with properties that can be used as methods. You can use it like this:

```
YourNamespace.someMethod();
```

Comment: and if I need to call someMethod from inside anotherMethod?

Comment: Then you declare them inside the anonymous function before the `return` statement (like the `privateData` variable) and then return references to them within the object being returned. (Only the functions returned in that object become public; other functions remain private.)

Comment: the thing is that sometimes the nested function can be call outside of the function, lets say we have f1() and f2() defined like in the answer, f2() calls f1(), but f1() is sometimes call directly by the user so it cant be private

Comment: So you declare it privately, and expose it. For example if you declare `f1` privately you could expose it as `yourMethod` with `return { yourMethod: f1 };`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside a wrapper object/ or  function.

```
var MyLibrary = {
    global1: 123,
    global2: 'abc',
    doSomething: function(a){
        // ...
    },
    somethingElse: function(b){}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are looking for [`Encapsulation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) in `Javascript`, then u are looking for [`Closures`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Closures)